# Locally-installed cli NPM project that is easy to execute

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line-interface

I'm building a cli node module. I would like people to be able to `npm install` it and use it right away with a command like `npm my-project --arg=foo`. It's meant for local project CLI use as a dev tool, not global installation.

It seems like the standard is to use [`bin`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin) in the `package.json`, but I don't understand some things about it:

1. When should I use `bin` and when should I use `scripts`?
2. How to I run the command in the including project? `npm my-project` doesn't do it.

Here is what I am doing now in `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "bin": "./cli.js"
}
```

And I can run it locally:

```
node cli.js --arg=foo
```

But when I `npm-install my-project` somewhere else, I don't know how to run the script it puts in bin (`npm run my-project` doesn't work), or if I'm using this correctly.

Comment: After a lot of learning and help from @robertklep, I've discovered there's no way to create a module for local installation that has a short executable path. You must use `./node_modules/.bin/my-project`. Fundamental misunderstanding. This is the reason `grunt-cli` exists, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start by explaining the difference between `bin` and `scripts`: the former you use if you want to provide a command line tool, the latter you use if you want to provide an additional command to `npm` (with some caveats though, see below).

In your situation, I think you want to use `bin`. However, instead of the user using `npm my-project --arg=foo`, they will use `my-project --arg=foo`, provided that your script is called `my-project`. To make that happen, your `package.json` will contain something like this:

```
"bin" : "./bin/my-project"
```

During installation, this will copy `./bin/my-project` to a "bin" directory (usually `/usr/local/bin` on Unix-like OS'es). During development, you can call it as `node bin/my-project`, or even just `./bin/my-project`, provided that it has correct permissions and ["shebang"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29).

**EDIT**: so I forgot that `npm` will use the package name, and not the name of the file in `./bin`, as the executable name (if `bin` is a string). If your package is called `my-project`, and you install the package (you need to use the `-g` flag before npm will install the executable), it will create an executable called `my-project`, regardless of where the `bin` property points to.

In other words:

```
package.json:
  "name" : "my-project"
  "bin"  : "./cli.js"

npm install -g:
   copies ./cli.js to /usr/local/bin/my-project and sets executable permissions
```

**END EDIT**

FWIW, storing CLI tools in `./bin` is convention, but not mandatory.

The `scripts` directive is useful for more internal purposes. For instance, you can use it to run a test suite, or linters, or pre/post install scripts.

Lastly, there are various modules available to help with command line parsing. I like [`docopt`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/docopt), but other often-used modules are [`commander`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander) or [`nomnom`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nomnom). You already mentioned [`yargs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs).

Comment: The only way I know to test this is change version, git tag, publish, npm install in depending project. Is there an easier way to test the way it makes the symlink? `npm link` is for global stuff and `npm unlink` is not symettrical for local packages (kind of a bug I think but I haven't dug into it)

Comment: @SimplGy see my edit regarding the `bin` property. As for linking: `npm unlink` will indeed not remove the symlink, which is annoying. As an alternative for using `npm link`, you can set the right permissions to the script in the package directory, and give it a shebang (which it needs anyway), so you can call it directly: `$ ./cli.js`

Comment: Set permissions, have shebang. Running from inside the project works. Think there's an issue specific to this being a local install, rather than a global one. I did the whole `version change publish npm install` loop, and the depending project now adds `node_modules/bin/my-project` as a symlink, but it's not in any $PATH I can find. I have restarted terminal, but I think maybe a local install isn't put in $PATH?

Comment: @SimplGy correct, you need a global install to get it installed to a common executable directory (like `/usr/local/bin`).

Comment: Right, but a global install is not appropriate for my use case (a dev tool). So my users have to do `./node_modules/.bin/my-project`?

Comment: @SimplGy if you don't want them to install your tool globally (which, even for devtools, isn't _that_ uncommon), then yes. I happen to have `./node_modules/.bin/` in my `$PATH` so I don't have to install globally, but I don't think you can assume a lot of devs did the same.